# Pacman won't install latest version

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I am trying to install the dbeaver package using the command `pacman -Syu dbeaver`. However, the version that is downloading and installing is older than what shows available on the Arch website.

pacman wants to install dbeaver-7.2.5-1. The website shows dbeaver 7.3.0-1 is available: https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/dbeaver/

I've tried `pacman -Syyu` to ensure everything's up to date. How do I get the newest available version?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem - it appears that some mirrors get updated faster than others.

Edit `/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist` - you should see entries like:

```
Server = https://mirror.bethselamin.de/$repo/os/$arch
Server = https://mirror.lnx.sk/pub/linux/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
...
```

Try to change the first server to a different mirror, then run `pacman -Syyu` again.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot figure out why your pacman fails to recover the latest version; `sudo pacman -Syy` should fix the problem. Maybe you have some conflict dependencies?

However, if you're not able to make pacman work properly, you always can download the PKGBUILD, clicking on *Source Files* on the right box of the Archlinux package page. Then you can download the PKGBUILD file ([this one](https://github.com/archlinux/svntogit-community/blob/packages/dbeaver/trunk/PKGBUILD)) and compile it on your own.

The complete procedure should be:

```bsh
mkdir tmp && cd tmp
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/archlinux/svntogit-community/packages/dbeaver/trunk/PKGBUILD
makepkg -si
# enjoy!
```